# Total electrical resistance of a material across different cross sectional area and temperature

Tags: electrical-engineering

It is given that the electrical resistance of a material is:

$R = \frac{\rho l}{A}$

Where $\rho$ is the electrical resistivity of the material, $l$ is the length of the traversing current through the material, and $A$ is the cross-sectional area.

Expanding this idea with varying cross-sectional area:

$R = \rho \int_0^l {\int_{y_{min}}^{y_{max}}{\frac{1}{A(x,y)} dy dx}}$

Now I want to also include the effect of temperature to the equation. I would like to know if which of these derivations is correct:

1.
$R(T_K) = \int_{T_{K,\infty}}^{T_{K,m}}{\rho (T_K) d(T_K)} \int_0^l {\int_{y_{min}}^{y_{max}}{\frac{1}{A(x,y)} dy dx}}$

2.
$R(T_K) = \int_{T_{K,\infty}}^{T_{K,m}}{\frac{d\rho}{dT} d(T_K)} \int_0^l {\int_{y_{min}}^{y_{max}}{\frac{1}{A(x,y)} dy dx}} = \left(\rho (T_{K,m}) - \rho (T_{K,\infty})\right) \int_0^l {\int_{y_{min}}^{y_{max}}{\frac{1}{A(x,y)} dy dx}}$

Where $T_K$ is the temperature in Kelvin, $T_{K,\infty}$ is the ambient temperature, and $T_{K,m}$ is the melting temperature.

If none of them are, could anyone show me how to correct it?

Comment: "varying cross sectional area" sounds like a fuse.

Comment: it indeed is. I am trying to model a metal strip as a fuse. @SolarMike